# Source Code for Magnolia Community Edition (v6.2)

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I am trying to locate the source code for Magnolia Community Edition (v6.2). I have downloaded the .war file from here https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Developing/Bundles-and-webapps.html but would like to know where I can find the associated source code for it too so that I can build the .war myself if possible?

I have browsed the following org repos but not entirely sure which code relates to the code used for the cms version I have downloaded.

- https://git.magnolia-cms.com/repos?visibility=public
- https://github.com/magnolia-cms

Answer (score 1):

The code is available at https://git.magnolia-cms.com/

The Projects page is a good starting point. Then going to PLATFORM and ce.pub gives you the community webapps shown in the bottom of the page you link.

To browse use
https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ce.pub/browse
or to clone https://git.magnolia-cms.com/scm/platform/ce.pub.git

The demo webapps are here: https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/demo-projects/browse/community

Comment: Thanks for the response Marten. So if I look in the ce folder it just has the details of deploying the community .war file so am I correct in assuming that the main source would be this here: https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/main.pub/browse/magnolia-core?